# Security: Sending email address in a url parameter

Tags: security

Is it considered bad security practice to include somebody's email address in a url as a parameter over http? The email address belongs to a client, and they may not want anybody to see it. The url points to my own domain, I'm just creating unique urls with email addresses as a parameter so I can detect who visited the url. Can anybody sniff http traffic to extract that info?

Comment: Are you sending these links in emails? Consider instead creating a database table mapping the user to a random token, and pass that token in the link.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's bad practice to put any personal information in the URL. A URL can be cached and viewed in so many ways. Even if you use SSL, URLs are still saved in your browser's history, so it just makes me cringe to pass non-public data in the URL. Usually it's not any more work to pass information in the body of a POST request, so that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you do it over `https`, as the URL path and querystring will be encrypted along with the body.

It's not a problem for the URL to be stored in the browser history, as that is private to the user.